# How to structure the component folders based on different user roles in react

Tags: reactjs

I will have users with two different roles (instructors and students) in my application. So far, I have implemented everything for one user role (instructor), and now I will start working on building the components for the other role. Many components will overlap but they will need to provide relatively different functionality. I wonder how I should structure the folders.

For example, I have a component called Assignment with the following folder structure:

```
=> components
   => Assignment
      => AssignmentList.tsx
      => AssignmentCard.tsx
```

This component will list all the assignments in the course for the current instructor.

I also need to build the `Assignment` component for the student to list the assignments available to her/him depending on the course registered currently. Probably, I can use `AssignmentCard.tsx` component since it simply presents the given assignment information.

I wonder if I should create a new folder named `Assignment_Student` or should I create two subfolders inside the `Assignment` folder for each role: `Student` and `Instructor (and maybe folder called`Common`to place the shared components, such as`AssignmentCard.tsx`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think that you shouldn't overthink about it, choose one and refactor when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the future. Currently, we're scratching our heads over structuring for students and instructor. Let's include about 5 hypothetical roles, e.g. Moderator, Administrator, Friends (not a good example but you get the picture).

Now we can better answer our question. From the way I see it, we have the following alternatives to choose from, with their own advantages and disadvantages.

**Structure 1**

```
=> components
    => shared
    => Assignment
        => Student
        => Instructor
        => Another hypothetical role
```

This, I believe will nicely isolate roles and their functionalities. But we are faced with 2 levels to deal with. We can improve it in the second option.

**Structure 2**

```
=> components
    => shared
    => StudentAssignment
    => InstructorAssignment
    => AnotherHypotheticalAssignment
```

This may prove to be cleaner than the first, we now have just one level of components to choose from. Better still, we don't have to scratch our heads if any of the shared components that was specific to the `Assignment` needs to be used in another place, say `ExtraCurricular`, we can simply get them from the shared, which is truly a **shared** component.

---

**TLDR** My suggestion is to use the second structure